# xtify with a webservice

Tags: android, notifications, push, xtify

is there any tutorial for Xtify notifications with the android, to get information from a webservice into an xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what "get information from a webservice into an xml file" means however Xtify's documentation is quite extensive.

Check out [Implementation Guide Android](http://console.xtify.com/implementation-guide-android) for details on how to get started.  I also highly recommend [downloading the SDK](http://console.xtify.com/android-download) which includes several sample Android apps which you can use as a guide.

There are couple of API's available:

- [Notification Configuration API](http://console.xtify.com/notification-configuration-api)
- [Push Notification API](http://console.xtify.com/push-notifications-web-service)

Comment: is the following I have an application that accesses an xml file that is updated periodically, I wanted to make a push for notification when these updates are made to fire a warning on the phone to the User open the application and check for updates

Comment: Take a look at the Push Notification API I mentioned above, it can be used for 'ad-hoc' notifications.